# How to start recording when something is said Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech

I am trying to make a program which uses speech recognition. Now I have a problem which I am running into, this is that you have to press a button or Enter to make the speech recognition start. Is there a way in which you say a phrase (kind of like Hey Google) that it starts recognizing speech in Python 3?
This is my code:

## Recording audio code:

```
r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    audio = r.listen(source)
x = r.recognize_google(audio)

print("I'm listening!")

try:
    print("You said: " + r.recognize_google(audio))
except speech_recognition.UnknownValueError:
    print("I am sorry but I couldn't understand you, try again.")
except speech_recognition.RequestError as e:
    print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Im afraid this is a bit tricky, if you think about it, google is effectively always listening. You have to keep listening till you get a catch phrase match, and then listen and react.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, essentially you have to break down your recognition into two parts: Keyword recognition (solely listening for a keyword) and the main recognition (recognizing what the user said after the keyword). Do know that this means your program will always be listening.

For the keyword recognition, you can use `Recognizer()`'s  `listen_in_background` method and scan for the keyword in whatever callback you give it. If the keyword is found, then you call `Recognizer().listen(source)`.

Since listening to keywords will require your program to constantly be listening and recognizing, you do not want to use any of the speech recognition APIs that require an internet connection (Bing, Google, Watson, Houndify, etc...). This is because all of these have monthly API limits that you will easily burn through. You want to save these APIs for actual recognition. I believe your only offline options are to use `recognize_sphinx` or snowboy hotword detection. I've never actually used Snowboy (though I hear it's pretty good) because it doesn't work on Windows (or at least it didn't when I was writing my program), but Sphinx has a keyword detection tool of sorts.

Basically, you pass the sphinx_recognizer keywords and how sensitive it should be to picking up those keywords via a tuple, and it will try to focus on finding those words in the speech. Beware that the more sensitive you make the keyword, the more false positives you'll get.

Here is an example:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import time

r = sr.Recognizer()

# Words that sphinx should listen closely for. 0-1 is the sensitivity
# of the wake word.
keywords = [("google", 1), ("hey google", 1), ]

source = sr.Microphone()


def callback(recognizer, audio):  # this is called from the background thread

    try:
        speech_as_text = recognizer.recognize_sphinx(audio, keyword_entries=keywords)
        print(speech_as_text)

        # Look for your "Ok Google" keyword in speech_as_text
        if "google" in speech_as_text or "hey google":
            recognize_main()

    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Oops! Didn't catch that")


def recognize_main():
    print("Recognizing Main...")
    audio_data = r.listen(source)
    # interpret the user's words however you normally interpret them


def start_recognizer():
    r.listen_in_background(source, callback)
    time.sleep(1000000)


start_recognizer()
```

This link is really helpful when working with the speech_recognition library:

https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/reference/library-reference.rst

Comment: So question, shouldn't callback be callback()? And which parameters should I use in there? Also recognize_main() is never called. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Lucool No, if you pass 'callback()' it will call the callback method when the interpreter gets to that line, and if that function returned something, it would pass its return value. 

In python, functions are "First Class", meaning they can be passed around like any variable or object. By using "callback" without the parentheses, we are telling the interpreter that we want to pass the function itself, not its return value. 

I have modified the code so that you can just copy/paste it and run it.

Comment: @Lucool 

If you are saying "Hey Google" or "Google" and never see it printed in the console, ensure that you set up your microphone correctly or that you're speaking clearly/loud enough. You can tweak the settings of the recognizer to adjust for ambient noise and other things that might throw off the recognition.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```py
from pocketsphinx import LiveSpeech
import os
for i in LiveSpeech():
    print(i)
    if "hey Google" in str(i):
       os.startfile("Your File.your_format")
#works Perfectly and if you want to hide python console then save as youfile.pyw
```